# AngularJs ui-routing - controller's method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular's ui-routing.
For example I have movies controller and there I have categories method and when user enter to /movies/categories I want to call this method

```
.state('movies', {
    url: '/movies',
    views: {
        'pageContent': {
            controller: 'movies',
            templateUrl: 'movies.html'
        }
    }
})
```

How can I achieve something like this:

```
.state('moviesCategories', {
    url: '/movies/categories',
    views: {
        'pageContent': {
            controller: 'movies',
            **method: 'categories',**
            templateUrl: 'categories.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute method on route change you can insert this code into categories.html

```
<div  data-ng-init="categories();"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in movies controler should add  $state.go('moviesCategories'); this method redirect to state moviesCategories

samples in documentation

```
.state('state1', {
  url: "/state1",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
})
.state('state1.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
  }
})
```

Comment: And if i have **/movies/categories/:slug** route, how can I guess which method must execute?

Comment: I edit answer. But a Don't correct understand word "method"? You want to call function in controller 'movies' ?

Answer (score 0):

Better create separate controllers for each route. let's say 'categoriesController'.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/movie',{
         templeteUrl:'templates/movies',
         controller:'moviesController'
    )
    .when('/movies/categories',{
         templeteUrl:'templates/movieCategories',
         controller:'movieCategoryController',
         resolve:{
              categories://pull categories using a service here. inside service write $http call.        
         }
    );
```

**inside controller**

```
//will inject the categories we got in reolve
angular.controller('movieCategoryController',['categories','$scope',functions(categories,$scope){

   $scope.categories=categories;
}]);
```